# selenium driver: get the tagname of a element

Tags: python, html, selenium, webdriver, element

I would like to get the name of the element data-test-carrier-name with python, more specific i want to get as a result "trenitalia".

The HTML part looks like this:

```
div class="_1moixrt _dtnn7w" tabindex="0"span data-test-carrier-name="trenitalia"
```

I tried it as followed but without any luck:

```
company = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="_1moixrt _dtnn7w"]')
company.get_attribute("data-test-carrier-name")
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! .Based on the class name `_1moixrt _dtnn7w` it seems like that is something that changes every time the webpage is loaded. Is there another way you can get to the element? For example look for an `id` tag that is human readable then drill into the element from there. Hope that make sense.

Comment: if the class name is dynamic (means chaanging after each page load)then please try to identify static element of your div and then use //div[contains(text(),'static text')] to get element before fetching attribute

Answer (score 0):

Please check element is visible before you start fetching its attribute.

```
org = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//div[@class="_1moixrt _dtnn7w"])[1]/span[1]')
    # Find the value of _1moixrt _dtnn7w?
    val = org.get_attribute("data-test-carrier-name")
```

Comment: search for random inputs on following site: https://www.thetrainline.com/en-us
I created a python script with selenium to scrap the output (times, prices, etc). The only expressions i couldnt gather is the carrier name..

Comment: what are you trying to do here? which element are you trying to access ?

Comment: I compiled the data and created a data frame since i want to make a empirical analysis about dynamic pricing. Now the last expression that i am not able to gather is the enterprise, ie. the tag of the attribute "data-test-carrier-name".
How can i gather for each connection the carrier name (here "trenitalia" or "italo" etc..) in order to compleete my data frame

Comment: please try above soluton

Comment: I tried, unfortunaltaly without success.. For example for the departure times i proceeded like this.. i locate the elements and then excract the texts of the elements:
dep_times = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="_1rxwtew "]')
dep_times_list = [x.text for x in dep_times]

For the carrier i am able to find and locate the elements but i cant find any approach to extract the name of the element itself. Do you know how to solve my issue?

Comment: with your solution i can only get the first attribute name, for example "trenitalia" but i dont get an iterated output of the name of the carrier of every single connection. now we can gather the first occurance.. how can we expand the syntax to get all attribute names? thank you very much until herer! :)

Comment: I would request you to accept this answer and raise another question with proper detail steps